# What is full form is jOPS in max-jOPS and critical-jOPS

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was reading about Garbage Collector performance and found the term `max-jOPS` and `critical jOPS`.

Link: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/333

Can someone tell the full form and explain what is it?

Answer (score 1):

These (`jOPS`, `max-jOPS` and `critical-jOPS`) are not GC terms.

---

I believe that you are referring to the terminology used in the `SPECjbb2015` Benchmark; e.g. https://www.spec.org/jbb2015/docs/userguide.pdf.  (This is confirmed by your update.)

The documents about the benchmark that I read don't specifically say what `jOPS` stands for.  However the [Glossary](https://www.spec.org/spec/glossary/) says that `OPS` stands for Operations Per Second, and I infer from the context that the `j` refers to `jbb2015`.

In other words, `jOPS` represents the rate at which a "unit of work" is performed by the `jbb2015` benchmark.  The unit is artificial, and is not designed to directly map to any real world measures ... though there will often be a correlation.

And the `max-jOPS` and `critical-jOPS` are specific points in the `RT` (Response-Throughput) curve that the benchmark captures.